# How to pass variable from axios get request to sub-component in vuejs?

Tags: arrays, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I do axios get request in following way:

```
index() {
   axios.get('/list/items').then(response => {
       this.items = response.data.items;
       this.stats = response.data.stats;
}
```

If I do `console.log(this.stats)` I see correct data listed as array.

I want to pass this data to a subcomponent like:

```
<stats :stats-list="stats"></stats>
or

<stats v-bind:stats-list="stats"></stats>
```

In my subcomponent I try to get this data like:

```
props: ['statsList'],
mounted() {
    console.log(this.statsList);
}
```

I get here undefined.

What should I do to get this data from parent component?

Comment: You are logging it when the component is mounted - till then the axios request hasn't been completed!

Answer (score 1):

Try this -

> v-if

```
<stats :stats-list="stats" v-if="statsList"></stats>
```

Let me know if it works!

Comment: It should work, can you give me access to something, like some repo or code snippet?

Comment: I created a var renderComponent = false, in axios after request I set it to true and call in your if, it seems to work now.

Comment: Clone this repo and check - https://github.com/siddhartharora02/vue-stack

Answer (score 0):

you should pass a initial value to stats, or use prop validation to set default value
computed works too.

```
props: ['rawStatsList'],
computed: {
  statsList(){ return this.rawStatsList? this.rawStatsList : []; }
}
```

use v-if will hide block until axios done, but notice that it won't show up if axios has error